# Configure Google Chart JS library (Loader.js) X axis: axis on top

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I was hoping that somebody had experience with the Google Charting JS library 'Loader.js'. I have a Timeline chart that I put together - generally it works fine, I can plot my data, it shows me a nice chart, etc. But I wanted to modify the resulting chart a bit, and it doesn't seem that the basic configuration options for this Chart type allow me to make the changes I want. I was hoping somebody with more experience had ideas on how to achieve:

1. Move the X axis so that it is showing at the top of the chart

Here's a JS Fiddle showing the chart and the source code: https://jsfiddle.net/ep28r9u0/1/

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  height: 95%;
}

.chart-height {
  height: 100%;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();


        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'TaskGroup' });   
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'bar label' });   
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip' });   
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });     
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' }); 

    dataTable.addRows( [
["Admin", "Test ABC ABC", "  • Test ABC ABC", new Date (2021, 9, 6), new Date (2021, 9, 15)]
, ["CAD", "#1 TEST", "  • #1  - TEST", new Date (2021, 9, 7), new Date (2021, 9, 8)]
, ["Field", "Field work - TEST TEST", "  • Field work - TEST", new Date (2021, 9, 6), new Date (2021, 9, 10)]
, ["CAD", "2 TEST TEST", "  • 2   -  TEST TEST", new Date (2021, 9, 11), new Date (2021, 9, 14)]
, ["Admin", "Test ITEM 1", "  • Test ITEM 1", new Date (2021, 9, 6), new Date (2021, 9, 10)]
, ["Field", "Test part 2", "  • Field Test part 2", new Date (2021, 9, 13), new Date (2021, 9, 15)]
, ["Field", "Test Part 3", "  • Field Test Part 3", new Date (2021, 9, 14), new Date (2021, 9, 17)]
]);

    var options = {
        timeline: { 
            rowLabelStyle: {fontName: 'Open Sans', fontSize: 24, color: '#603913' },
            barLabelStyle: { fontName: 'Tahoma', fontSize: 14 },
            colorByRowLabel: true         // not sure I need this, if using the in-line Style as a Column
        }
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="chart-height" id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
J

Comment: there are no config options that will move the x-axis to the top.

Comment: Well... darn.  :(